# Reshape y_train for binary text classification in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

i have a classical y_train which is composed of 0 (negative) and 1 (positive) in a one dimensionnal shape. I wanted to train a tensorflow model but i have to initialize the y placeholder with the number of classes i want. So in this text classification case, i want the model to check negative or positive value so 2 classes ? But how did i convert my y_train to fit the output that i'm looking for. Thanks for your time!

```
"ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (25000, 1) for Tensor u'Placeholder_5:0', which has shape (Dimension(None), Dimension(2))"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears your `y_train` contains the label values themselves, whereas the `y_train` needed by the model requires label probabilities. In your case, since there are only two labels, you can convert that to label probabilities as follows :

```
y_train = tf.concat(1, [1 - y_train, y_train])
```

If you have more labels, have a look at [`sparse_to_dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html#sparse_to_dense) to convert them to probabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the issue has moved... Maybe you could take a look at my small try : https://gist.github.com/jesuisnicolasdavid/95ff6f20c07965574d10

Comment: Can you please describe the issue you are facing in this thread?