# TensorFlow for binary classification

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I am trying to adapt [this MNIST example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html) to binary classification.

But when changing my `NLABELS` from `NLABELS=2` to `NLABELS=1`, the loss function always returns 0 (and accuracy 1).

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf

# Import data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('data', one_hot=True)
NLABELS = 2

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Create the model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='x-input')
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, NLABELS]), name='weights')
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([NLABELS], name='bias'))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

# Add summary ops to collect data
_ = tf.histogram_summary('weights', W)
_ = tf.histogram_summary('biases', b)
_ = tf.histogram_summary('y', y)

# Define loss and optimizer
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, NLABELS], name='y-input')

# More name scopes will clean up the graph representation
with tf.name_scope('cross_entropy'):
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_mean(y_ * tf.log(y))
    _ = tf.scalar_summary('cross entropy', cross_entropy)
with tf.name_scope('train'):
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(10.).minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.name_scope('test'):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    _ = tf.scalar_summary('accuracy', accuracy)

# Merge all the summaries and write them out to /tmp/mnist_logs
merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('logs', sess.graph_def)
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

# Train the model, and feed in test data and record summaries every 10 steps

for i in range(1000):
    if i % 10 == 0:  # Record summary data and the accuracy
        labels = mnist.test.labels[:, 0:NLABELS]
        feed = {x: mnist.test.images, y_: labels}

        result = sess.run([merged, accuracy, cross_entropy], feed_dict=feed)
        summary_str = result[0]
        acc = result[1]
        loss = result[2]
        writer.add_summary(summary_str, i)
        print('Accuracy at step %s: %s - loss: %f' % (i, acc, loss)) 
   else:
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        batch_ys = batch_ys[:, 0:NLABELS]
        feed = {x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys}
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=feed)
```

I have checked the dimensions of both `batch_ys` (fed into `y`) and `_y` and they are both 1xN matrices when `NLABELS=1` so the problem seems to be prior to that. Maybe something to do with the matrix multiplication?

I actually have got this same problem in a real project, so any help would be appreciated... Thanks!

Comment: I am trying your netwrok and it dosen't seem to be working, have you found a possible solution ?

Comment: I see that you're initializing all of your weights to 0. I think the model's not going to work because everything gets multiplied by zero.  I would change that to  
 W=tf.get_variable('weights'[in_dim,out_dim],initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer())

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The original MNIST example uses a [one-hot encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) to represent the labels in the data: this means that if there are `NLABELS = 10` classes (as in MNIST), the target output is `[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]` for class 0, `[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]` for class 1, etc. The [`tf.nn.softmax()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax) operator converts the logits computed by `tf.matmul(x, W) + b` into a probability distribution across the different output classes, which is then compared to the fed-in value for `y_`.

If `NLABELS = 1`, this acts as if there were only a single class, and the `tf.nn.softmax()` op would compute a probability of `1.0` for that class, leading to a cross-entropy of `0.0`, since `tf.log(1.0)` is `0.0` for all of the examples.

There are (at least) two approaches you could try for binary classification:

1. The simplest would be to set `NLABELS = 2` for the two possible classes, and encode your training data as `[1 0]` for label 0 and `[0 1]` for label 1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35205193/3574081) has a suggestion for how to do that.
2. You could keep the labels as integers `0` and `1` and use [`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits), as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35227732/3574081).

Comment: Oh, I see the problem... But now I wonder, should I use cross entropy at all for a binary classification problem then? This guy who has implemented a neural network by hand has not used cross entropy for his binary classification problem: http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/

Comment: That's certainly possible. You could have a single output unit, feed it through `tf.nn.sigmoid()` to get a value between 0 and 1 and then use `y - y_` as the loss function.

Comment: doesn't TensorFlow try to minimize the loss function? It has to be a scalar, right? Should I do something like `sum(abs(y-y_))`?

Comment: You could try the `tf.nn.l2_loss()` op instead of `sum(abs(…))`.

Comment: Usually the logarithmic loss would be a good choice used in combination with a single output unit. Logarithmic loss is also called binary cross entropy because it is a special case of cross entropy working on only two classes (check http://www.exegetic.biz/blog/2015/12/making-sense-logarithmic-loss/ for a more detailed explanation).

In Keras you can use binary_crossentropy. In TensorFlow you can use log_loss.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for good examples of how to implement binary classification in TensorFlow in a similar manner to the way it would be done in Keras.  I didn't find any, but after digging through the code a bit, I think I have it figured out.  I modified the problem here to implement a solution that uses sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits the way Keras does under the hood.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf

# Import data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('data', one_hot=True)
NLABELS = 1

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Create the model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='x-input')
W = tf.get_variable('weights', [784, NLABELS],
                    initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer()) * 0.1
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([NLABELS], name='bias'))
logits = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

# Define loss and optimizer
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, NLABELS], name='y-input')

# More name scopes will clean up the graph representation
with tf.name_scope('cross_entropy'):

    #manual calculation : under the hood math, don't use this it will have gradient problems
    # entropy = tf.multiply(tf.log(tf.sigmoid(logits)), y_) + tf.multiply((1 - y_), tf.log(1 - tf.sigmoid(logits)))
    # loss = -tf.reduce_mean(entropy, name='loss')

    entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=logits)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropy, name='loss')

with tf.name_scope('train'):
    # Using Adam instead
    # train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.002).minimize(loss)

with tf.name_scope('test'):
    preds = tf.cast((logits > 0.5), tf.float32)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(preds, y_)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

# Train the model, and feed in test data and record summaries every 10 steps

for i in range(2000):
    if i % 100 == 0:  # Record summary data and the accuracy
        labels = mnist.test.labels[:, 0:NLABELS]
        feed = {x: mnist.test.images, y_: labels}
        result = sess.run([loss, accuracy], feed_dict=feed)
        print('Accuracy at step %s: %s - loss: %f' % (i, result[1], result[0]))
    else:
        batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        batch_ys = batch_ys[:, 0:NLABELS]
        feed = {x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys}
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=feed)
```

Training:

```
Accuracy at step 0: 0.7373 - loss: 0.758670
Accuracy at step 100: 0.9017 - loss: 0.423321
Accuracy at step 200: 0.9031 - loss: 0.322541
Accuracy at step 300: 0.9085 - loss: 0.255705
Accuracy at step 400: 0.9188 - loss: 0.209892
Accuracy at step 500: 0.9308 - loss: 0.178372
Accuracy at step 600: 0.9453 - loss: 0.155927
Accuracy at step 700: 0.9507 - loss: 0.139031
Accuracy at step 800: 0.9556 - loss: 0.125855
Accuracy at step 900: 0.9607 - loss: 0.115340
Accuracy at step 1000: 0.9633 - loss: 0.106709
Accuracy at step 1100: 0.9667 - loss: 0.099286
Accuracy at step 1200: 0.971 - loss: 0.093048
Accuracy at step 1300: 0.9714 - loss: 0.087915
Accuracy at step 1400: 0.9745 - loss: 0.083300
Accuracy at step 1500: 0.9745 - loss: 0.079019
Accuracy at step 1600: 0.9761 - loss: 0.075164
Accuracy at step 1700: 0.9768 - loss: 0.071803
Accuracy at step 1800: 0.9777 - loss: 0.068825
Accuracy at step 1900: 0.9788 - loss: 0.066270
```