# Tensorflow: converting classification example to a perceptron

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to convert the multi-layer MNIST example [Tensorflow Mechanics 101](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.html#tensorflow-mechanics-101) into a multi-layer perceptron, that would output a value between 0 and 1 for the input sample, instead of classifying it using `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

I see an answer by @mrry to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277898/tensorflow-for-binary-classification), however, I am not sure how to replace the final part (`loss` and `evaluation`) of the [current graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist.py) with the `tf.sigmoid` as suggestd by @mrry.

The idea is: to train a model using only positive examples (without any labels) and then have it output the value between 0 and 1 for the likelihood of a test sample resembling positive training samples. Does it make sense?

Our current implementation is a two-class inference model adapted from the Tensorflow Mechanics tutorial, that is fed using positive/negative feature vectors associated with the appropriate labels.

Is there a Tensorflow example that does what we would like to achieve?

Comment: Just replace the: `cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
logits, labels, name='xentropy')` with `cross_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
logits, labels, name='xentropy')` the sigmoid outputs 0 to 1

Comment: Hi Bob, thank you very much for the reply. I saw this method, and unlike `sparse_softmax_*` it requires <https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits> `targets` instead of `labels`, and I am not sure what these targets are, since the inference model expects them to be of a different dimension than the labels (I have a 2-class classification model)

Comment: Here is the difference: `sparse_softmax...` only one label is set to 1 all others are 0 example on the picture it is a bike. `softmax...` the sum of the labels are 1 so a thing can be 20% bike 80% something else, unlike sparse where a thing can be only one thing. and finally `sigmoid...` has no constraint every output/target is separate from each other and can be from 0 to 1. example, one output will indicate it is a bike another will indicate it has wheels, another will say it is 0.4 red other 0.6 blue and so on. So to answer targets is the same as labels but with different constraints.

Comment: Aha ok I got what you're asking, `sigmoid_*` and `softmax_*` both require same dimension targets and labels the size [batch, num_outputs], but `sparse_*` requires only 1 number per example, so [batch, 1] = [batch].