# Zero cost in tensorflow multi perceptron

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I have built a simple neural network to classify data into only 2 classes
Data is something like this

```
34.62365962451697,78.0246928153624,0
60.18259938620976,86.30855209546826,1
```

There are no zero values in data so there's no source of such cost.Cost is zero with adagrad optimiser and nan with gradient descent optimiser 
Here's the code

```
import numpy as ny
import tensorflow as tf


def load():
    data = []
    for line in open("ex2data1.txt"):
        row = line.split(',')
        x = ny.array(row, dtype='|S4')
        data.append(x.astype(ny.float64))
    return ny.array(data)


def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    # Hidden layer with ReLU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    # Hidden layer with ReLU activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

# Store layers weight &amp; bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 15])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([15, 15])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([15, 1]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([15])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([15])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))
}

data = load()
Xdata = ny.array(data[:, 0:2])
Ydata = ny.array(data[:, 2])
Ydata = ny.array(Ydata.reshape([100, 1]))
# Step 2 - Create input and output placeholders for data
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 2], name="X")
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1], name="Y")

pred = multilayer_perceptron(X, weights, biases)


# Minimize error using cross entropy
with tf.name_scope("cost"):
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=Y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cost)
    tf.summary.scalar("cost", cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    print(Xdata)
    print(Ydata)

    # Step 12 train the  model
    for i in range(1000):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: Xdata, Y: Ydata})
        if (i % 100 == 0):
            print(sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: Xdata, Y: Ydata}))
```

Comment: First of all, are you normalising all values between 0 and 1. Second of all, _what makes you think zero cost is not possible_. Zero cost basically means you have a perfect match with the training data (you may be overfitting). Having a zero cost in no way is related to 0 values being in your test data.

Comment: Data is fine, i already tested same data in octave.Nvm,problem is solved .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the way your labels are represented you should not use this loss function. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277898/tensorflow-for-binary-classification) is relevant

Comment: Well, the label representation was the problem , i had to make 2 classes in form of [1,0] or [0,1] for proper working of cost function.Don't know why though